# Ruby on Rails: How to set up "find" options in order to not use cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, search, find, ruby-on-rails-3

In Ruby on Rails you can find records from the database with this syntax:

```
<model_name>.find_by_<field_name>()
```

Examples: `User.find_by_email('test@test.test')`, `User.find_by_id(1)`, ...

Time ago, if I am not wrong, I read somewhere that you can explicitly disable caching for 'find' operations, but I can not remember how.

Can someone help me remember?

Comment: I've not seen caching setup by default... Are you sure? did you check your logs?

Comment: I agree with apneadiving. I don't think it is cached by default.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `ActiveRecord::QueryCache.uncached` like this:

```
User.find_by_email('test@test.test')
User.find_by_email('test@test.test') # Will return cached result

User.uncached do
  User.find_by_email('test@test.test')
  User.find_by_email('test@test.test') # Will query the database again
end
```

In a controller, it would look something like this:

```
def show # users#index action
  User.uncached do
    @user = User.find_by_email('test@test.test')
    @another_user = User.find_by_email('test@test.test') # Will query database        
  end

  User.find_by_email('test@test.test') # Will *not* query database, as we're outside of the Users.uncached block
end
```

Obviously, in a model, you just have to do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.do_something
    uncached do
      self.find_by_email('test@test.test')
      self.find_by_email('test@test.test') # Will query database
    end
  end
end

User.do_something # Will run both queries
```

Comment: I didn't understand how to use these codes: what I have to put instead of 'self.find(...)'? Can you make a practical example?

Comment: I've updated my examples but it's difficult when you're just giving me abstract code. Do you want to use this in a controller or in a model? If controller, you can use my first example. If model, you can use my last. It might be easier if you post what you're trying to do, instead of me trying to come up with examples that make sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: assuming Rails3, since Rails2 doesn't have default caching.)

This should work as you want it to out of the box:

1. Queries caches are destroyed after each action ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html paragraph 1.5)
2. In addition, it seems (http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/2/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-activerecord-explicit-caching) that caches are also destroyed on attribute/record updates

Do you have a specific use case not covered by the default configuration?

Comment: I am trying to resolve this problem someway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636704/chache-problem-running-two-consecutive-http-get-requests-from-an-app1-to-an-app2